# How to do isolated word recognition using pocketsphinx

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I tried to follow this link for isolated word recognition
[Speech to text for single word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637872/speech-to-text-for-single-word)
But when I am providing -keyphrase, it is giving me the result (keyphrase word) even if I am giving a wrong keyphrase.
Is this expected?

Comment: You need to play with threshold to avoid false activations

Comment: Will doit for sure but I am not able to understand its significance? It is explained as "Threshold for p(hyp)/p(alternatives) ratio", but I am not able to get anything out of it.



I experimented with it a bit. The sound file contains the only word "apple", 
command: pocketsphinx_continuous -infile apple.wav -keyphrase "kp" -kws_threshold "kt", results:
format: keyphrase used & kws_threshold range (For one time detection), 
apple (1e-20,1e-32), car (1e-21,1e-22), cash (1e-23,1e-26), doctor (1e-42,1e-46), mango (1e-34,1e-39), hole (1e-18,1e-23)

What does all these signify?
Thanks